# NGINX Use Custom/Map variable in if block

Tags: cookies, nginx, config

NGINX 1.9x / RHEL

I am trying to return a 204 for certain request if a cookie is not set. I cannot get the nginx.conf file to pass config test or restart. The first IF block is failing when trying to test against the MAP variable created.

```
    http block...
    map $http_cookie $my_login_cookie {
      default 0;
      "~hello_logged_in" 1;
    }


    Server Block....

    location ~ /$ {

      if ($my_login_cookie = 0) { <<<<<< Statement is not working
          if ($args ~ "^Blah=(.*)") {
            return 204;
          }
       }
    }
```

I have found many examples of code that shows this kind of thing should be doable. WHAT AM I MISSING?!?!

<<<<<< UPDATED FINAL WORKING CODE >>>>>>

```
    http block...
    map $http_cookie $my_login_cookie {
      default 0;
      "~hello_logged_in" 1;
    }

    Server Block....

    location ~ /$ {

      set $my_redirect y;

      if ($my_login_cookie = 0) {
         set $my_redirect "${my_redirect}e";
      }

      if ($args ~ "^blah=(.*)") {
         set $my_redirect "${my_redirect}s";
      }

      if ($my_redirect = "yes") {
          return 204;
      }

   }
```

Comment: My applogizes for posting bad code. My curly bracket go eaten when I added the note (<<<<< Statement is not working). The correct code is up there now. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested ifs and multiple condition ifs are not supported by nginx.

Your missing a { after if ($my_login_cookie = 0) otherwise you would have recieved the following warning `"if" directive is not allowed here` on the `if ($args ~ "^Blah=(.*)") {` line.

Possible solution for your config:

```
# test whether my_login_cookie is set
if ($my_login_cookie = 0) {
  set $test C;
}

# test
if ($args ~ "^Blah=(.*)") {
  set $test "${test}A";
}

# if both of the above tests are true return
if ($test = CA) {
  return 204;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing the following         set $my_redirect y;
    
          if ($my_login_cookie = 0) {
             set $my_redirect "${my_redirect}e";
          }

          if ($args ~ "^blah=(.*)") {
             set $my_redirect "${my_redirect}s";
          }

          if ($my_redirect = "yes") {
              return 204;
          }